# Browser forward f:event not working in Prettyfaces

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I am using JSF 2.2 and  Primefaces 5.1 with prettyfaces in my project.My problem when I back button press to initializePage method is call.But again press browser go forward button action  intializePage is not call it happen only use prettyfaces. If I remove **prettyfaces** in web.xml it works fine.

```
<h:body>
<f:event listener="#{user.initializePage}" type="preRenderView" />
<p:panel id="topId" header="Main" > 
...
<p:commandButton value="Button" action="#{user.buttonaction}"/>
..... 
</p:panel>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Does it work if you **don't** use PrimeFaces (since I do not see any related PF tag)

Comment: @Kukeltje Face issue in PrettyFaces not a PrimeFaces.When remove PrettyFaces in web.xml to press PrimeFaces commandbutton forward button action works fine.But add PrettyFaces in web.xml same operation is not working.

Comment: So an `h:commandButton` (with ajax) instead of a PrimsDaces one also fails?

Comment: @Kukeltjie h:command button works fine. In browser history  goforward click I face issue in action.

Comment: Did you put an `f:ajax` tag inside the `h:commandButton`?`

Comment: Problem not in command button . I faces problem in  Browser history forward(->) arrow press f:event listener is not working

Comment: if the problem is NOT related to the commandButton, it is NOT Primefaces related.